# Meaning of "stub your toe" (apply too much cologne to oneself)?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard an older person say "Pheew! What did you do -- stub your toe?" The implied meaning was that when I put on cologne, I must have stubbed my toe. This caused me to pour an exorbitant amount on myself, thus causing a strong odor of cologne.

Has anyone out there ever heard of this phrase and that definition of it?

Ah yah.

Thank you.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stub+toe+against

Comment: ***Stub one's toe against something and stub one's toe on something***: 
*to ram one's toe accidentally against some hard object. Don't stub your toe against that brick in the path. Claire stubbed her toe against one of the legs of the sofa. I stubbed my toe on the bottom step*.

Comment: Thank you both, but that meaning does not apply.

Comment: @londonderry what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I heard an older person say "Pheew! What did you do -- stub your toe?" The implied meaning was that when I put on cologne, I must have stubbed my toe. This caused me to pour an exorbitant amount on myself, thus causing a strong odor of cologne.

Has anyone out there ever heard of this phrase and that definition of it?

Comment: I think he meant that you accidentally hit against  a bottle of cologne.

Comment: @londonderry yes, I have heard the phrase. There, you have the definition and a link to dictionary.

Comment: Makes sense then, huh?

Comment: @londonderry am I missing something? Could you make your question clearer?

Comment: Pheew! You're smelling like a perfume factory! https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22obfusticating%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdif7bwsfLAhXCwxQKHX3mBEMQ_AUIBygA&biw=1024&bih=672&dpr=2#q=%22smelling+like+a+perfume+factory%22

Comment: @Josh61's meaning is correct.  There's nothing special in the meaning here to do with perfume - the speaker just implied that you spilled extra cologne by accident, that's all.

Comment: It sounds like something my grandfather would have said when pouring an 'inappropriately' full glass of whisky.

Comment: Never heard the idiom "stub your toe" used with that meaning.  Usually it's applied literally to the act of, uh, stubbing your toe on something.

Answer (score 5):

My dad used to use that term to mean "to use too much" like, when some dish is too salty, he'd say "Wow - that's salty!!  Looks like you stubbed your toe there."